Can anyone suggest some way to mock a Google Cloud Speech-v2 gRPC speech client in Go
import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    package speech ("cloud.google.com/go/speech/apiv2")
)

func GSTTClient() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    opts := []option.ClientOption{}
    if client, err := speech.NewClient(ctx, opts...); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("failed to create new client")
    } else {
        return client
    }
}

This is the code sample how I am creating the gRPC client. But I am not able to figure out how to return a mock client which I will further use in unit testcases.
Currently testcase is making a network call which gets an actual google stt gRPC client. But I am expecting a mock client.

package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "os"

    speech "cloud.google.com/go/speech/apiv2"
    speechpb "google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/cloud/speech/v1"
)

type SpeechClientInterface interface {
    Recognize(ctx context.Context, req *speechpb.RecognizeRequest, opts ...interface{}) (*speechpb.RecognizeResponse, error)
}

type MockSpeechClient struct{}
func (m *MockSpeechClient) Recognize(ctx context.Context, req *speechpb.RecognizeRequest, opts ...interface{}) (*speechpb.RecognizeResponse, error) {
    return &speechpb.RecognizeResponse{}, nil
}

func NewMockSpeechClient() *MockSpeechClient {
    return &MockSpeechClient{}
}

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    client := NewMockSpeechClient()

    req := &speechpb.RecognizeRequest{}
    resp, err := client.Recognize(ctx, req)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "failed to recognize: %v", err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("Response: %v", resp)
}


I guess your test code may look like this:
client_test.go:
package client

import (
    "context"
    "testing"
)

func TestRecognize(t *testing.T){
     ctx := context.TODO()
     resp,err := Recognize(ctx, &speechpb.RecognizeRequest{ text:"some text"})
     if err!=nil {
         t.Fatal(err)
     }
     if resp!= "some result" {
        t.Fatalf("expect result to be 'some result', actual: %s",resp)
     }
}

The Recognize:
func Recognize(ctx context.Context,req *speechpb.RecognizeRequest) (string,error){
    client := GSTTClient()

    resp, err := client.Recognize(ctx, req)
    if err != nil {
        return "",err
    }
    return parseResponse(resp)
}

func parseResponse(resp *speechpb.RecognizeRequest) (string,error){
   ...
}

The problem is, Recognize uses the client internally, you cannot pass a client to it, and I think you may also do not want to pass it.
The solution is rather simple, monkey patching:
package client

import (
    "context"
    "testing"
    "github.com/xhd2015/xgo/runtime/mock"
)

type mockClient struct {
    *Client
}

func (c *mockClient) Recognize(ctx context.Context,req *speechpb.RecognizeRequest) (*speechpb.RecognizeResponse,error){
     return &speechpb.RecognizeResponse{}, nil
}

func TestRecognize(t *testing.T){
     ctx := context.TODO()
     mock.Patch(GSTTClient, func() *Client {
          return &mockClient{}
     })
     resp,err := Recognize(ctx, &speechpb.RecognizeRequest{ text:"some text"})
     if err!=nil {
         t.Fatal(err)
     }
     if resp!= "some result" {
        t.Fatalf("expect result to be 'some result', actual: %s",resp)
     }
}

Notice the mock.Patch(GSTTClient,...), we actually bypass the GSTTClient function, instead return a mock client that implements the Recognize method.
